# Not able to get Biztalk host instance status using Powershell

Tags: powershell, biztalk, powershell-3.0, biztalk-2010

I am using the below script to get the host instances state from a remote server in the same domain.

```
    $servers = ("usxxxxxxx01")

 function checkhostinstancestatusstarted ($server)
 {

$hostinstances = get-wmiobject MSBTS_HostInstance -namespace 'root\MicrosoftBizTalkServer'  | where {$_.runningserver -match $server -AND $_.hosttype -ne "2" -and $_.IsDisabled -ne    "True"}

write-host "Checking the state of all host instances on the server $server"

foreach ($hostinstance in $hostinstances)
    {
    $HostInstanceName = $HostInstance.hostname

    #Checks the host instance state
    if ($HostInstance.ServiceState -eq 1)
        {
        write-host "$HostInstanceName`: Stopped."
        }
    elseif ($HostInstance.ServiceState -eq 2)
        {
        write-host "$HostInstanceName`: Start pending."
        }
    elseif ($HostInstance.ServiceState -eq 3)
        {
        write-host "$HostInstanceName`: Stop pending."
        }
    elseif ($HostInstance.ServiceState -eq 4)
        {
        write-host "$HostInstanceName`: Started."
        }
    elseif ($HostInstance.ServiceState -eq 5)
        {
        write-host "$HostInstanceName`: Continue pending."
        }
    elseif ($HostInstance.ServiceState -eq 6)
        {
        write-host "$HostInstanceName`: Pause pending."
        }
    elseif ($HostInstance.ServiceState -eq 7)
        {
        write-host "$HostInstanceName`: Paused."
        }
    elseif ($HostInstance.ServiceState -eq 8)
        {
        write-host "$HostInstanceName`: Unknown."
        }
    }
write-host `n    
}

foreach ($server in $servers)
{
checkhostinstancestatusstarted $server 
}
```

I am getting this exception. But BizTalk is configured in the server and host instances are in running status.

> Get-WmiObject : The server has not been configured. To configure the server, run the BizTalk Server Configuration wizard and configure the Group feature. At line:10 char:3 + Get-WmiObject -Class "MSBTS_HostInstance" -Namespace 'root\MicrosoftBizTalkSer ... + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], COMException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMICOMException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand

Anyone knows what the issue is? Or if you have a better version of the script, that ll be helpful too or any Cross domain scripts .

Note: my local machine is on PSv3 and remote BizTalk server is on v2.

Comment: just a note: My local server from where i am trying to execute the script is on PSv3 and biztalk server is on v2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the [BizTalk PowerShell Provider](http://psbiztalk.codeplex.com/) for this task. The BizTalk 2010 version (1.2.0.4) works with PowerShell 2. If you are in the possibility of using it, you can simply use the following commands to get the status of your host instances:

```
cd BizTalk:
Set-Location '..\Platform Settings\Host Instances'
Get-ChildItem
```

Sample output:

```
Path: BizTalk:\Platform Settings\Host Instances

Name                Host Name           Windows Group       Running Server      Host Type           Service State
----                ---------           -------------       --------------      ---------           -------------
Microsoft BizTal... BizTalkServerApp... LABO\BizTalk App... JM-BT1              InProcess           Running
Microsoft BizTal... BizTalkServerIso... LABO\BizTalk Iso... JM-BT1              Isolated            NotApplicable
Microsoft BizTal... ReceiveHost         LABO\BizTalk App... JM-BT1              InProcess           Running
Microsoft BizTal... SendHost            LABO\BizTalk App... JM-BT1              InProcess           Running
Microsoft BizTal... ProcessHost         LABO\BizTalk App... JM-BT1              InProcess           StopPending
Microsoft BizTal... TrackingHost        LABO\BizTalk App... JM-BT1              InProcess           Running
```